# Nginx cookbook v 2.0.0: Cookbook http_gzip_static_module not found

Tags: deployment, nginx, chef-infra, cookbook, berkshelf

I'm using berkshelf to manage cookbooks, chef 11.6.2, and nginx cookbook v 2.0.0

my settings to compile nginx from source:

```
set[:nginx][:source][:modules] = ["http_gzip_static_module", "http_ssl_module"]
```

The provisioning gives me the error:

```
Cookbook http_gzip_static_module not found. If you're loading http_gzip_static_module from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
```

Is it a bug from nginx cookbook and how do you solve it? Everything works well with nginx cookbook v 1.7.0

Many thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The nginx cookbook version was increased to 2.0.0 to make an emphasis on breaking changes. Particularly now you should specify all modules with **nginx::** prefix and do not use **extra_modules** at all. So, it should look like this now:

```
"default_attributes": {
    "nginx": {
      "source": {
        "modules": [
          "nginx::http_gzip_static_module", "nginx::http_ssl_module",
          "nginx::http_realip_module", "nginx::http_stub_status_module",
          "nginx::upload_progress_module"]
        }
    }
}
```

Please look at this [ticket](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/COOK-3549) and relevant [changeset](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/nginx/commit/bccc005) for details.

Comment: Hi Mike, many thanks for your answer, I will try it and head back soon.